# Unable to connect to node.js server using HTTPS

Tags: node.js, https, openssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

I'm using Node.js 10.0.0 and trying create a node server that uses HTTPS.
I followed this [documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server/) to create the needed certs and keys etc.

I can connect from localhost to the node server just fine. However, if a Windows machine on the same network as the device running the node server tries to connect to the server using HTTPS the browser says "Trying to establish a secure connection" and times out and the page fails to load.

What am I doing wrong? I'm new to node and HTTPS etc. What can I do to debug this problem?

Comment: Check the MTU settings on all hosts involved. Usually, broken TLS = MTU problems.

Comment: I guess the Windows machine has no way of knowing that the self-signed cert is valid unless you install the cert on it?

Comment: @RobertKawecki, the machine connecting to the node server is running Windows and the machine running the node server is running Linux. I'll check the MTU's. But I'd imagine they both have the default MTU of 1500 or 1492.

Comment: @Christian, normally a browser will warn you that the connection may not be secure because the cert is self-signed. But it will still establish an SSL/TLS connection. Right?